# Can't install Geany-plugins-* It requires geany-plugins-common which is installed

Tags: plugins, installation, centos7, geany

CentOS 7.2 is my OS

I installed 1.27 geany from EPEL Repo. It was successful, and then I just tried to double click the geany plugins rpms to add them one by one which was successful when I did in CentOS 6.7, but it failed.

Then I tried terminal:(debugger plugin in this example)

```
[root@localhost geany-plugins]# yum install geany-plugins-debugger-1.27-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Examining geany-plugins-debugger-1.27-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm: geany-plugins-debugger-1.27-1.el7.centos.x86_64
Marking geany-plugins-debugger-1.27-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package geany-plugins-debugger.x86_64 0:1.27-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: geany-plugins-common = 1.27-1.el7.centos for package: geany-plugins-debugger-1.27-1.el7.centos.x86_64
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.syringanetworks.net
 * epel: mirror.prgmr.com
 * extras: mirror.pac-12.org
 * updates: mirrors.usc.edu
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: geany-plugins-debugger-1.27-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (/geany-plugins-debugger-1.27-1.el7.centos.x86_64)
           Requires: geany-plugins-common = 1.27-1.el7.centos
           Installed: geany-plugins-common-1.27-1.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
               geany-plugins-common = 1.27-1.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

It requires geany-plugins-common and it then lists the exact thing as installed

What is the problem?

Comment: This is a packaging issue or an issue with your local package database. Please file a bugreport against centos. Off topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its offtopic as bugreport against CentOS